# Linear Algebra, Hoffman and Kunze, Chapter 8.3, page 292

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, inner-products

A small problem that I somehow cannot figure out.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, $f$ a linear functional on $V$, and $W$ be the null space of $f$.
The author tries to prove that $V = W + W^{\perp}$.

On page 292, suppose $f\neq 0$. Then $f$ is of rank $1$ and $\dim(W^{\perp}) = 1$.
([page 292](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf7Hc.jpg), see upper right)

Why $\dim(W^{\perp}) = 1$?

[Reference]
[Theorem 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtAfW.jpg)
[Theorem 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaBCX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\dim W=\dim\ker f=n-1$ (unless $f=0$, in which case $\ker f=V$). So,\begin{align}\dim W^\perp&=\dim V-\dim W\\&=n-(n-1)\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! But $V = W + W^{\perp}$ is what the author tries to prove here.

Comment: No, it is not. That's proven in theorem 5. What the authors are proving here is that $f$ is completely determined by its restriction to $W^\perp$.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just completely misunderstood what the author tries to show here. Let $W$ be the null space of $f$. Since $W\subseteq V$ and $V$ is finite-dimensional, so is $W$. By Theorem 5, we have $V=W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$. (note that for any finite-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$, we can always find such an orthogonal projection $E$ in theorem 5, see Theorem 4)